# my html created html in my to do list keeps disapering when i reload the page

Tags: javascript

i know that the problem is that let todoList is an empty array, but i dont know how to solve it.

the id tags in my created html is so e can create a delete button later

heres my code:

```
const textArea = document.querySelector("textarea");
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const listContainer = document.querySelector(".list-container");

let id = 0;
let todoList = [];

button.onclick = function () {
  const listItem = {
    title: textArea.value,
  };

  todoList.push(listItem);
  addToStorage(todoList);
  const dataFromStorage = getFromStorage();
  createHtml(dataFromStorage);
  };

function addToStorage(items) {
  const stringify = JSON.stringify(items);
  localStorage.setItem("list", stringify);
 }

function getFromStorage() {
  const data = localStorage.getItem("list");
  const unstrigified = JSON.parse(data);
  return unstrigified;
 }

const createHtml = (data) => {
  id++;
  listContainer.innerHTML = "";
  data.forEach((item) => {
    listContainer.innerHTML += `<div class="list-item" data-id=${id}><p>${item.title}   </p><button class="remove" data-id=${id}>Delete</button></div>`;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in the code is as follows

1. Initially the todolist will be an empty array. so when you do the below

```js
todoList.push(listItem);
// adding to local storage which will override the existing todos when page is refreshed 
addToStorage(todoList);
// So when the below line is executed only the latest todo will be returned
const dataFromStorage = getFromStorage();
createHtml(dataFromStorage);
```

### Fix:

Initialise the todos from localstorage instead of an empty array

```js
let todoList = [];
// change it as below
let todoList = getFromStorage();
```

Now Modify the `getFromStorage()` as below

```js
// If the data is present in the localStorage then return it, else return empty array
function getFromStorage() {
  const data = localStorage.getItem("list");
  if (!data) return [];
  const unstrigified = JSON.parse(data);
  return unstrigified;
}
```

Now when the page is loaded, we need to display the todos. Add the below lines of code

```js
window.onload = function () {
  createHtml(todoList);
};
```

That's it. This will fix the issue.

Few minor improvements can be made as well.

```js
todoList.push(listItem);
addToStorage(todoList);
const dataFromStorage = getFromStorage(); // this line is not necessary, remove it
createHtml(dataFromStorage); // change this to createHtml(todoList)
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/knirmalkumar/pen/JjvBPKM)

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpfull and educational.

Comment: You're Welcome! Glad I was able to help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is you just forgot to load the data from `localStorage` when the page loaded like this

```
window.onLoad = () => {
  const dataFromStorage = getFromStorage();
  if(dataFromStorage){
     createHtml(dataFromStorage);
  } else {
    createHtml([]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you  good sir. Im a student and just started learning javascript, and i understand your solution. I just did not know that was something you could do. 
I